# How to disable weekends in the ajax calender extender?

Tags: asp.net

I have implemented the following code: this function not call

My Html Code is:

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" PopupPosition="BottomRight" Enabled="true" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="DisableWeekends" TargetControlID="txtStartDate">

onclientshown=`"DisableWeekends"
```

The function is give below:

```
function DisableWeekends(sender, args) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sender._days.all.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if (sender._days.all[i].id == "DisabledWeekendsCalendar" + j + "_5") {
        sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
        sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = 
               "<div>" + sender._days.all[i].innerText + "</div>";
      }

      if (sender._days.all[i].id == "DisabledWeekendsCalendar" + j + "_6") {
        sender._days.all[i].disabled = true;
        sender._days.all[i].innerHTML = 
               "<div>" + sender._days.all[i].innerText + "</div>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just review the accepted answer in the following LINK http://forums.asp.net/t/1689931.aspx

Comment: thanks but my problem is that i have added function in the head tag but it is not called in calender                          <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yy" 
                                            PopupButtonID="ImageButton1"  PopupPosition="BottomRight"  Enabled="true"  OnClientDateSelectionChanged="DisableWeekends" 
    
                                            TargetControlID="txtStartDate">

Comment: now your problem is solved or not??

Comment: no my function is not called when i call it in calender extender onclentshown property.  Please help me

Answer (score 1):

**Using CSS**

```
.DisableWeekends .ajax__calendar_days table tbody tr td:first-child
{

    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

After that add `DisableWeekends` class in `CalendarExtender` controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //disable sunday
        function detect_sunday(sender, args) {
            if (sender._selectedDate.getDay() == 0) {
                sender._selectedDate = new Date();
                // set the date back to the current date
                sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format));
                alert("You can't select sunday!");
            }
        }
    </script>

<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calenderExtender" runat="server" CssClass="cal_theme" TargetControlID="txtCalender"
            PopupButtonID="BtnCalender" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="detect_sunday"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it's not working actually nothing is reflect and when i use breakpoints control not shifted to  detect_sunday function. So my problem is function is not called.